# SET inside SELECT (MySQL) PROCEDURE

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to get is the `user_discount.percent` inside the `DiscountVar`.

So in `THEN SET` I can return a single value `discount = DiscountVar`.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE DiscountVar FLOAT(28,10);

IF EXISTS 
(
SELECT
    user_discount.percent as DiscountVar,
    user_discount.link_id,
    user_discount.pacc_id,
    user_discount.timestamp_valid
FROM 
    user_discount
WHERE 
    user_discount.link_id = wo_id 
AND user_discount.pacc_id = pacc_id
AND UTC_TIMESTAMP>=user_discount.timestamp_valid
ORDER BY 
    user_discount.timestamp_valid DESC
LIMIT 1
)

THEN SET discount = DiscountVar;

ELSE SET discount = 0;
END IF;

END
```

Is this possible?

---

I've tried this `user_discount.percent AS percent INTO @DiscountVar` but it didn't work...

---

The `IF EXISTS` on it's own works. I'd just need to do a second select just to output the data in `THEN`.

Answer (score 0):

An alias in the query is not equivalent to a procedure variable. If you want to assign to a variable, use [`SELECT ... INTO`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).

You can also use an assignment with `:=`. But I think you have to use a user variable with an `@` prefix, not a declared variable.

When you execute a query with `EXISTS`, it just tests whether the query matches any rows, it doesn't execute the assignments. Instead of using `EXISTS`, perform the `SELECT` and check whether the variable is set.

```
BEGIN

SELECT
    @DiscountVar := user_discount.percent,
    user_discount.link_id,
    user_discount.pacc_id,
    user_discount.timestamp_valid
FROM 
    user_discount
WHERE 
    user_discount.link_id = wo_id 
AND user_discount.pacc_id = pacc_id
AND UTC_TIMESTAMP>=user_discount.timestamp_valid
ORDER BY 
    user_discount.timestamp_valid DESC
LIMIT 1;

SET discount = IFNULL(@DiscountVar, 0);

END
```

Comment: But if you remove `user_discount.link_id`, `user_discount.pacc_id` and `user_discount.timestamp_valid` we get an error. Because they are used in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: We must have those in `SELECT`. But how do we cast `user_discount.percent`  into the `DiscountVar ` then?

Comment: You can assign to a user variable with `:=`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It returns `NULL` again... Is the User variable not accessible to `THEN SET discount = DiscountVar;`?

Comment: It's `@DiscountVar` now.

Comment: Yes I know...`THEN SET discount = @DiscountVar;` But it returns NULL. I even removed the DECLARED one.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if anything in the `SELECT` list is executed when you use `EXISTS`. That operator may just check whether any rows match the join criteria.

Comment: It worked before. But then we had to repeat the same query in `THEN` just to get the output which is not optimal. If you have any other suggestions to replace `EXISTS` do tell please?

Comment: See my updated answer. Get rid of the `IF EXISTS` and just test the variable.